# How to Use Google Analytics API for Business Pages

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Can anyone tell me is it possible to add Google Analytics API in my website so that each business user can see their analytics data in their dashboard.

I have a business directory website where 650k businesses are listed and every business has their own separate page in website

The registered users can access to their business dashboard where I like to show them Analytis data like pageviews, new users, bounce rate etc through Google Analytics.

Like Raven-tools, moz etc

Is it possible?

Comment: You could construct a query of Core reporting API for the pageviews of that particular page, and then display it on that page. The problem you will run into is that you will need to make these requests server side and display these results only to the owners of those pages can see their dash board, thus you'll likely want to use a service account. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py